# Joomla 3.3.1 articles disappearing from front end after one year

Tags: articles

We have thousands of articles listed as published on our Joomla 3.3.1 website and blog but could not work out why we could only see about 100 articles on the front end.

We have now worked out that articles stop displaying after one year despite none having a "Finish Publishing" date.

We've looked everywhere and cannot work out why this would be happening.

Any ideas?

Comment: In the admin area, article manager, are the articles showing a green tick/red x/yellow exclamation mark? Check that you have your time zone set correctly in “Site -> Global Configuration -> Server”.

Comment: Hi Johnny, All articles have a green tick. I have checked under System > Global Configuration > server and time zone is set correctly to Brisbane. Would you have any other suggestions? Many thanks. Trish

Comment: Which component are you using? is this com_content or something else?

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 possibilities for this scenario:

- The articles are there, but not displaying on the website.
- The articles were deleted from the database.

First, you will need to check if the articles are still there, and you can easily verify that they're there by checking the backend or the `#__content` table. If they're there, then they might not be displaying because:

- Their status is set to something other than public.
- There is a limit on how many articles are displayed on the homepage.
- Their publishing time has expired
- Their associated category was disabled (In most cases, this is the cause of the issue)

If the articles are not there, then your best bet would be to revert to database backup that had these articles.

Answer (score 1):

Could some of the articles have been archived either manually or automatically via a plugin such as [AutoArchive](https://extensions.joomla.org/extension/autoarchive) or similar?